# Which 'contact information' format has the broadest support for mobile phone QR code scanners?

Tags: mobile-phones, barcode-scanner, vcf-vcard, qr-code, hcard

vCard? mecard? hCard?

Is there a de facto standard at this point? I've never personally owned a 'smartphone' -- is there a format that's supported 'out-of-the-box' for either iphone, android or blackberry?

edit:

- found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/zxing/browse_thread/thread/97fa9470b6f7f886/0942b3e46abb4252?show_docid=0942b3e46abb4252&pli=1) discussion from last
     year. Any thoughts?

  - [this](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GetTheReader) reader appears to be multiplatform and uses mecard
  - [mecard spec](http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/imode/make/content/barcode/function/application/addressbook/index.html)

Comment: mecard spec has moved, it is now here: http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/developer/make/content/barcode/function/application/addressbook/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out vCard, although verbose, has the broadest support.

Mecard is a de facto (read: avoid at all costs) standard

Answer (score 2):

hCard is a vcard that supports html in data. Mecard, is a very lite version of vcard. One line with important info. vCard, is a format to exchange contacts data. Allot of version there.